# PHP, MySQL. Сортировка пользовательских данных.

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

Всем привет!

Возьмем аудиозаписи во ВКонтакте, как пример. Их можно сортировать, как душа пожелает, передвигая мышкой. А с технической точки зрения как это работает? В API есть такие вещи, как before и after (типа после чего стоит запись и перед чем).

А как потом выводить это в отсортированном виде? Может есть другие варианты решения такой задачи?

Answer (score 1):

Тут есть принципиальная разница для кого делается сортировка. Как у вк - персональная для каждого пользователя или глобальная - например вы сортируете пункты меню на своем сайте для всех пользователей.

В первом случае вам нужно хранить данные о сортировке в дополнительной таблице, с привязкой к сортируемому объекту и пользователю. Во втором же сортировку можно хранить прямо вместе с данными.

Хранить сортировку можно разными способами.

Самый простой - пронумеровать записи: 1, 2, 3, 4 итд. Это очень легко, наглядно и просто для вывода данных. Просто делаете выборку с сортировкой по нужному полю. Но есть проблема с перемещением записей. При перетаскивании 100500й записи в самое начало придется обновить поле сортировки у всех записей между старой и новой позицией. Для больших обьемов данных это может стать критичным.

Второй вариант - хранить id предидущей и последующей записи. Этот способ гораздо проще для перемещения. Обновить данные прийдется максимум для 5 записей:
Перемещаемой, тех между которыми она стояла, и тех между которыми она встанет. Но повышается сложность вывода отсортированного списка. Вам прийдется самому строить список, выбирая каждый последующий елемент.

В общем исходить нужно из ваших данных. Если их мало и вывод данных делается гораздо чаще изменения порядка то вам подойдет первый способ. Если же данных много и вы только и будете их сортировать - можете подумать о втором.